# Tap Target for rectangular shapes Android

Tags: android, taptargetview

I am trying to use the Tap Target View library from GitHub in an android app.

https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView

I was wondering if anyone knows if we can use this library to highlight a rectangular shape or if it is primarily for targets that can be surrounded by a circle. I like to highlight an entire row in a list view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This library when reviewing the codes you find out there is no arc or circle in this customView and is a Rect...

So how is this circle like? It cause the radius number it gets. so if you know you can change the code very easily and remove or make the radius to 0.

But my question is why? really is going to make a bad mess for rectangular things...